# CSS Full height responsive website

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a full height responsive site with a sticky fixed height footer and no scrolling.  I have this so far...

```css
body, html {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

.content {
  text-align:center;
  background:wheat;
  height:calc(100vh - 100px);
 }
 
 .image_container img {
   max-width:100%;
   height:auto;
 }

footer {
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  height:100px;
  background:teal;
  width:100%;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

<div class="content">
    This is the content
    <div class="image_container">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/500x1000/500/fff">
    </div>
</div>
<footer>This Is The Footer</footer>

</div>
```

The image is causing everything to scroll, how can I make this image height responsive?

Comment: What you mean by: "Make the image height responsive"?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking, how do you intend to manage content overflow if you disable scrolling ?

Answer (score 1):

I recently created a similar page and once I had to insert features like scroll-steps and navigation buttons, I found fullPage.

Try [fullPage.js](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) - I think it has all the functionality build in you need.

Comment: Can you explain a little more? This is just a link but no real solution per se

Comment: Link-only answer usually gets deleted

Comment: Is it better now? :)

Answer (score 1):

This may helpfull

```css
body, html {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

.content {
  text-align:center;
  background:wheat;
  height:calc(100vh - 100px);
 }
 
 .image_container img {
   max-width:100%;
   
 }
 .image_container{
 height:100%;
 }

footer {
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  height:100px;
  background:teal;
  width:100%;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
}
img{
max-height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

<div class="content">
    This is the content
    <div class="image_container">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/500x1000/500/fff">
    </div>
</div>

<footer>This Is The Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite easy, using `flex`.

I set `.container` to be a *flexbox*, setting `.content` to a dynamic height of 100% and the `footer` to a fixed height of `100px`.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
  text-align: center;
  background: wheat;
  height: 100%;
}

.image_container img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
  background: teal;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="content">
    This is the content
    <div class="image_container">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/500x1000/500/fff">
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer>This Is The Footer</footer>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

go with this one

just give a

```
.image_container{height: 100%;}
.image_container img { max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%;}
```

and you are good to go this approach keep image aspect ratio
as you can see in sample

like this

```css
body, html {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

.content {
  text-align:center;
  background:wheat;
  height:calc(100vh - 100px);
 }
.image_container{
   height: 100%;
}
 .image_container img {
   max-height: 100%;
   max-width: 100%;
 }

footer {
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  height:100px;
  background:teal;
  width:100%;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

<div class="content">
    This is the content
    <div class="image_container">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/500x1000/500/fff">
    </div>
</div>
<footer>This Is The Footer</footer>

</div>
```